# ApplicationContext is null in onResume

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, sharedpreferences

i woke up this morning to this error. i am unsure what it only happens in the onResume of my fragment. since it cant get ApplicationContext i cannot access my shared preferences.

here is my onresume code

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mMediationAgent != null) {

        mMediationAgent.onResume(getActivity());

    } else {
        mMediationAgent = SupersonicFactory.getInstance();
        mMediationAgent.setRewardedVideoListener(this);
        mMediationAgent.initRewardedVideo(getActivity(), mAppKey, mUserId);
    }
    setupAd();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
    int x = sharedPref.getInt("count", 0);
    Log.e("tree", "whats x" + Long.toString(x));
    if (count != 0) {
        ct.start();
        updateText(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this in you `onCreateView` for first time initialization.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref ;

sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
```

Comment: You can ask anytime :)

Comment: To charity. I still get the null but it seems to be successfully committing things to shared preferences. I haven't had time to test retrival on the preferences